# Applying function to pandas DataFrame column gives numpy error

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, mean

This seemed at first to be a basic process but I keep getting the following error:

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not iterable
```

I have a pandas DataFrame with a person and his performance.  I want to find the average of his top two performance scores.  I wrote the following function

```
def second(num):
    bk = max(num)
    count = 0
    m1 = m2 = float('-inf')
    for x in num:
         count += 1
         if x >= m1:
             m1, m2 = x, m1
        elif x > m2:
            m2 = x
    return np.mean([m2, bk]) if count >= 2 else None
```

The DataFrame looks like this:

```
            Person  Rat
8612    Jeff Smith  2.4
9178    Jeff Smith  7.2
9767    Jeff Smith  9.9
10359   Jeff Smith  9.6
10963   Jeff Smith  6.6
11515   Jeff Smith  4.9
12095   Jeff Smith  3.2
12697   Jeff Smith  1.1
```

I did the following and received an error:

```
df['avg'] = df.Rat.apply(lambda x: second(x))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to sort `df` first, and then use `groupby` and aggregate with `head` and `mean`:

```
>>> df.sort_values('Rat', ascending=False).groupby('Person').agg(lambda x: x.head(2).mean())
             Rat
Person          
Jeff Smith  9.75
```

This will give you the mean of each person's two highest ratings.

Comment: @user2989523 I think it may be because `df.Rat.apply(lambda x: second(x))` is applying the function to each (float) value in the column, not the column as a whole. Lines such as `for x in num` will cause an error to be thrown (`num` is a float).

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
 In [5]: df = pd.read_clipboard()

 In [6]: df
 Out[6]:
           Person  Rat
8612  Jeff  Smith  2.4
9178  Jeff  Smith  7.2
9767  Jeff  Smith  9.9
10359 Jeff  Smith  9.6
10963 Jeff  Smith  6.6
11515 Jeff  Smith  4.9
12095 Jeff  Smith  3.2
12697 Jeff  Smith  1.1
```

Sort the dataframe on `Rat`

```
In [18]: df = df.sort("Rat", ascending=0)

In [19]: df
Out[19]:
           Person  Rat
9767  Jeff  Smith  9.9
10359 Jeff  Smith  9.6
9178  Jeff  Smith  7.2
10963 Jeff  Smith  6.6
11515 Jeff  Smith  4.9
12095 Jeff  Smith  3.2
8612  Jeff  Smith  2.4
12697 Jeff  Smith  1.1
```

Get the average of the top two values of `Rat`.

```
In [21]: avg = df.head(2).loc[:, "Rat"].mean()

In [24]: avg
Out[24]: 9.75
```

Answer (score 0):

As written, you are applying your function to a `Series` not to a `DataFrame`.  When you run `Series.apply`, your function gets applied iteratively to each element of the series, rather than to the series as a whole.  (This is why you're getting the iteration error.)

When you call `DataFrame.apply`, things are different: in that context your function gets applied iteratively to each column (or row) in your dataframe.

Try: `df['avg'] = df[['Rat']].apply(second)`.  Notice that I put `df[['Rat']]` **not** `df['Rat']`.  The extra set of brackets forces the slice to return a single column dataframe rather than a series.

Does that work?